# generating pdf files with sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file from inside a sidekiq worker.
Although I am making a new instance of ActionView and including AppHelper and Routes, I still don't have any styles inside the pdf (no layout is considered).

Here's the code:

offer_worker.rb:

```
def perform(offer_token)
  @offer = Offer.unscoped.find_by_offer_token!(offer_token)
  view = html = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.root.join('app/views'))
  view.class.include ApplicationHelper
  view.class.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  rendered = view.render(
    :template => "displays/offer_template_one.html.erb",
    :layout => "layouts/templates.html.erb",
    :locals => { :@offer => offer}
  )
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(rendered)
  save_path = Rails.root.join('public', 'offer.pdf')
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf
  end
    save_path
end
```

controller method:

```
def download
  OfferWorker.perform_async(@offer.offer_token)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your views and layouts using the `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` helper to make your CSS paths absolute?

Comment: did you ever get this working?